# Creating Cloud Monitoring alerts based on BigQuery Table information

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-monitoring

I want to create alerts based on tables in a specific dataset. The alerts should be triggered if a table has not been modified since a specified time.

How would I go about this using Cloud Monitoring?

Comment: Do you know how the table is updated? Load Job? Query? Streaming? In fact, can you isolate the logs that told you the table has been updated?

Comment: I think it's a load job.

Comment: If it's a load job it's pretty simple to get the log entry. Create a log based metric on that log and create an alert with Cloud Monitoring, to send an alert with you have a not entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Cloud Monitoring alerts based on BigQuery Table information by following these steps:

1. Go to the Cloud Console and select your project.
2. In the navigation pane, click on "Monitoring".
3. Click on "Create Policy".
4. In the "metric drop-down menu, select "BigQuery Dataset" then choose "logs-based" then "log-entries".
5. In the "Filter" section, select the dataset you want to monitor.
6. In the rolling window function, choose "count"
7. In the "Conditions" section, select "threshold" as the metric, "below" as position, and threshold value as "2".
8. Set notifications channel and name alert policy
9. Create Policy